# Skip androidx.startup when running instrumented tests

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I have some startup initializers defined in my manifest file.

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.myapp.MyInitializer"
  android:value="androidx.startup" />
```

That initializer is being run when I run my instrumented tests, really slowing things down.  Is there a way to disable startup when running android instrumented tests?

Comment: in theory you could remove the entire `androidx.startup.InitializationProvider` from your test app, would that work? Or you only are interested in removing a specific initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Then you should remove Automatic initialize components by replacing

```
android:value="androidx.startup"
```

with this

```
tools:node="remove"
```

Now you have to Manually initialize components whenever you want

```
AppInitializer.getInstance(context)
.initializeComponent(MyInitializer::class.java)
```

Like this.

You can read this for more reference

[Manually initialize components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup#manual)

Answer (score 0):

replace android value for startup with following `android:value="androidx.startup"` =>
`tools:node="remove"`